# Converting a Byte Array into a Bitmap Image

Tags: c++, arrays, bitmapimage, data-conversion

I have a byte array named `pBuffe` of type `unsigned char* pBuffer` that was fed an 'image' (a bunch of bytes) by a high powered camera after it captured a picture.  How do I go about converting this byte array into a viewable bitmap image file?

Comment: What is exactly "data for an image" ? What is "viewable bitmap image" ?

Comment: I have a byte array pBuffer that was fed an 'image' (a bunch of bytes) by a high powered camera.  I am trying to convert this array of bytes into a bitmap image.  By viewable image i just mean what i said.  I don't care if it just displays it in a window or saves it as a file, i just want the bitmap image to be viewable on the screen.  and sorry for the vagueness i have literally no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't need to do much if you choose [XBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) and have an image viewer or a web browser supporting it. The next simplest formats would be [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) and [PCX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCX).

Comment: If you're program runs on Windows, this tutorial may help you: [C++ Bitmap Tutorial](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate?  All I've been able to find on the subject is converting the other way (bitmaps to byte arrays).

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) or its simplified C++ wrapper [png++](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/) to write out PNG images, which take up a lot less space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this easily by using the well-known and popular [EasyBMP](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/) library. It creates the proper file header and everything you need for it. As a bonus, it supports multiple platforms.